# excecute the laravel vendor publish command when install the project

Tags: laravel, command

forgive me my poor English.I am a newbie to Laravel. I made a blog project with laravel 5.5 . The project includes  packages that wrote by other people.There is one package that need to execute php artisan vendor:publish command after installed with composer.I have uploaded my project to github. When other people install my project, I  want them to install my project without  running the vendor:publish command .  How can I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a new [command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#generating-commands) which runs all other command that you need to run in order to bootstrap your project including other packages vendor command.

A bootstrap ommand like:

```
php artisan make:command  bootMyProject
```

dispatch  events at the end of the general command and use the events to trigger others commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the command to your `composer.json` file under `scripts` section.

For example, you want `artisan vendor:publish` to run automatically after `composer install` you can add it to `post-install-cmd`

```
"scripts": {

        ...

        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "php artisan vendor:publish"
        ],

        ...
    },
```

You can check [composer document](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) for detail